# Cannot connect node.js and socket.io to my front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying like this, but anyway see only `cannot get /`

```
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);

const io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/public")))
server.listen(5000);
```